# ARCore Baisc Application Crashes

Tags: android, arcore

I am using MOTOG7 play.
some times my application comes up and crashes after plan is detected. some times after the object is randered. Can you please let me know what I am missing.

==
Log Cat:

provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.502 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.

```
--------- beginning of crash
2020-08-11 17:53:05.518 10471-10516/com.example.arpoject11 A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0x91d5f662 in tid 10516 (SyncThread), pid 10471 (mple.arpoject11)
2020-08-11 17:53:05.689 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 1.75341 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.689 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.702 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 1.84135 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.702 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.832 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 1.88667 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.833 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.893 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 1.92521 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:05.893 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.021 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 1.98669 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.022 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.096 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 2.06285 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.096 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.221 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 2.14496 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.221 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.296 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: vio_fault_detector.cc:142 VIO is moving fast with speed (m/s): 2.20629 but RANSAC failed to provide valid frame to frame translation by reporting degeneracy.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.296 10471-10542/com.example.arpoject11 W/native: pose_confidence_estimator.cc:261 Ransac provided translation vector is very small.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.349 10471-10471/com.example.arpoject11 E/native: hit_test.cc:381 generic::internal: No point hit.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.382 10471-10471/com.example.arpoject11 E/native: hit_test.cc:381 generic::internal: No point hit.
2020-08-11 17:53:06.416 10471-10471/com.example.arpoject11 E/native: hit_test.cc:381 generic::internal: No point hit.
```

My Code is very very basic.

```
package com.example.arpoject11;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.net.Uri;
```

...
...    import android.view.View;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private ModelRenderable modelRenderable;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        setUpModel();
        setupPlane();
    }
     private void setUpModel(){
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.mesh_chimpanzee)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(renderable->modelRenderable=renderable)
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"model cannot be loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return null;
                });
    }
    private void setupPlane(){
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(new BaseArFragment.OnTapArPlaneListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTapPlane(HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Anchor anchor= hitResult.createAnchor();
                AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
                createModel(anchorNode);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createModel(AnchorNode anchorNode){
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        node.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
        node.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Crash is device-dependent. This is not seen on other devices. only MOTO. There is no support from MOTO (on their ARCORE) as mentioned by their call center people. only generic support.

Closing with this answer as this is device-specific only.